# Yii framework logger : Remove the path

Tags: php, yii

I am using the yii log to log my events. Here is my sample log

```
[2013-05-24 11:58:29.015965] [debug] [SiteController] this is debug test
in D:\work\www\cs360rnd\trunk\protected\controllers\SiteController.php (79)
in D:\work\www\cs360rnd\trunk\index.php (16)
```

I want to remove the below line from log

in D:\work\www\cs360rnd\trunk\index.php (16)

Does anyone has idea how i can remove it from log layout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are backtrace entries.

Do you want to remove line with `index.php`? (1)

Or you want to leave only the first(with `SiteController`)? (2)

(1) and (2) are not the same if you have more that two elements in callstack.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/YiiBase.php#L458
see line #462.

First, debug backtrace is logged with log-message only if you are in debug mode.

Second,

If your goal is (1) - I'm afraid you need to exdend `Yii` class, override `log` method and use it instead of built in.

If your goal is (2) - `YII_TRACE_LEVEL` should be equal to 1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for extending the class and not as the majority that says to change the framework :)